# get assembly code generated by JavaScript compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, assembly, v8, trace

I am using v8 / Node 8.8 with Ignition and Turbofan and tried to get the assembly code that is generated by my JavaScript but so far the asm and code outputs are same in the size independent of actual code differences.

So `node --trace-hydrogen --trace_phase=Z --trace_deopt --code_comments --hydroge
n_track_positions --redirect_code_traces --trace_hydrogen_file=test.js --print_
code test.js` seems to only output the code of the compiler itself, not the code behind the processed JS code.

What are the needed flags for Ignition / Turbofan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignition, being an interpreter, does not produce assembly code.

For Turbofan, the flag is `--print-opt-code`.

Comment: Are there prebuilt binaries with debugging enabled? It does not work with the node binary by default.

Comment: There are no prebuilt binaries that I know of. Disassembler support is on-by-default in Debug builds. In Release builds, depending on your build system, you need either `make disassembler=on x64.release` or the GYP flag `-Dv8_enable_disassembler=1` or `v8_enable_disassembler = true` in your `args.gn`.

Comment: Current builds do not use make anymore, they use the gclient toolchain based on Python. Where do I find the debug builds for all platforms? Also the gyp build is deprecated afaik.

Comment: Yes, the GYP build is deprecated, but Node still uses it. -- I don't know what you mean by "the gclient toolchain"; V8 can only be built with GYP and GN (its `Makefile` is a convenience wrapper around the former). -- As I said, I'm not aware of any prebuilt binaries with disassembler support, and that includes Debug binaries. You'll have to compile your own.

Comment: Also, turns out `--print-opt-code` *should* work with the node binary by default, see: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/common.gypi#L32

Comment: Unfortunately `node --print-opt-code file` does nothing or I missed some other flags. Also `--print-code` and others work but the output files (.asm and so on) have the same number of lines and same filesize.

Comment: Maybe your testcase is so short that nothing gets optimized? `--trace-opt` would tell you.

Comment: `node --print-opt-code --trace-opt test.js` outputs nothing

Comment: So indeed nothing gets optimized. Try calling your function 10,000 times or so.

Comment: I guess we can not get the assembly code that is generated in the background if there are no optimizations done? http://www.mattzeunert.com/2015/08/19/viewing-assembly-code-generated-by-v8.html I need the assembly code of the original code without any changes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9igDWV5ZUg&feature=youtu.be&t=930

Comment: Those links are outdated. `--print-opt-code` prints all generated machine code. Without/before optimization, execution is handled by "Ignition", which is a bytecode interpreter, so there is no "assembly code that is generated in the background".

Comment: So there is no reliable way to always get the assembly code for further analysis without forcing optimization? As I already wrote, `.-print-opt-code` outputs nothing in most cases. So the bytecode is only shown if it is optimized?

Comment: `--print-opt-code` *is* reliable. Without optimization, *there is no generated assembly code*, so of course there is no way to get something that doesn't exist. --- Bytecode is never optimized. You can dump the bytecode with `--print-bytecode`, but it is bytecode, not assembly code.

Comment: At least `--print-bytecode` is useful for direct comparisons between 2 different methods.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the code of the node/v8 engine but keep the code of the analysed js file? 1.8MB is quite much overhead.

Comment: V8 itself doesn't print any (byte)code on startup. I don't know what you're seeing; I would guess it's Node's initialization/startup. Anyway, `--print-bytecode --print-bytecode-filter=my_function` only prints the bytecode for `function my_function(....) { ... }`.

Comment: Exactly. Without this I get much more, possibly by Node.